# Algorithm for a minimization problem of a function that is not differentiable under a constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, regression, numerical-optimization, constraints

I'm trying to understand an algorithm for a minimization problem but it is unclear. Here is the function we consider

$\lVert Y - X\beta\rVert_{2}^{2} + \lambda\lVert\beta\rVert_{1}$ where $Y\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times d}$

This function is not differentiable everywhere since the $l-1$ norm is composed of the absolute value function from what I observe. I have find the following algorithm to try to minimize this function, and it is somewhat unclear :

1. Put $\beta=0$
2. Consider $\nabla g(\beta)=\lVert Y - X\beta\rVert_{2}^{2}$, we know that at the minimum, $\nabla g(\beta)=0$ so we will try to reach 0 step by step as follows
3. Take the greatest coordinate of $\nabla g(\beta)$ in absolute value, say $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_i)\rvert$ and moves $\beta_i$ until $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_i)\rvert$ equals the second greatest value, say $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_j)\rvert$
4. Then moves $\beta_i$ and $\beta_j$ such until $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_i)\rvert$ and $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_j)\rvert$ reach $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_k)\rvert$ and repeat this $d$ times
5. Then we obtained a vector $\beta$ that "minimizes" $\nabla g(\beta)$ and moreover, we see that the largest coordinate, say $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_i)\rvert$ is the one that contributes the most to the minimization.

Here is my questions : Why do we put $\beta=0$ ? I thought it was to take the first order condition on $\lVert Y - X\beta\rVert_{2}^{2}$ but this is not the case.

It leads me to my second question : Why don't just take the derivatives with respect to  $\lVert Y - X\beta\rVert_{2}^{2}$ since this expression is differentiable ?

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Note that $\nabla g(\beta)$ is not necessarily $0$ at the minimum. The correct first-order optimality condition is that $-\nabla g(\beta) \in \lambda \partial \|\beta\|_1$, where $\partial \|\beta\|_1$ denotes the subdifferential of the $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: @VHarisop Thank you a lot this precision, however I don't know what is a subdifferential, but I am noting that something is wrong in this algorithm. Do you have a hunch about what's going on inside this algorithm ?

Comment: I don't quite understand this algorithm. For example I don't understand what it means to "move $\beta_i$ until $|\nabla g(\beta_i)|$ reaches $|\nabla g(\beta_k)|$".

Comment: It means (from my understanding) that since  $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_i)\rvert\geq\lvert\nabla g(\beta_k)\rvert$ we can moves $\beta_i$ until the function $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_i)\rvert$ equals the function $\lvert\nabla g(\beta_k)\rvert$. But I don't see why the first inequality should be true when we start to moove the $\beta_i$ to be honest since this inequality holds when we are considering $\beta =0_{\mathbb{R}^d}$

Comment: How would you implement "moving" $\beta_i$? I don't see an obvious way to do it.

Comment: I don't see it also to be honest but it exists (larsfunction on Rstudio) It's from a paper in multivariate statistics and this explanation is provided in few lines.  The name of this algorithm in statistics is Least square angle regression  and I would like to see an "optimization" point of view of this problem instead of a statisics point of view (based on correlation and so on), what this article tries to do in a ambiguous way